# How to call multiple Activity through single intent(from widget)?

Tags: android, android-intent, parallel-processing

I'm looking for an answer to the question where on an event i want to open two activity `parallely` where one of them will be in background and another in foreground but when the foreground activity stops the background activity should fire up.

Is it possible? I would like to know the trick

**@downvoters kindly comment if you find it useless**

**Update**

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityTwo.class);
        Intent home= new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        Intent[] intents={intent,home};
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivities(context,0,intents,0);
```

But this is opening only the `MainActivity` class.
where i want it to open the `Activitytwo` class in the foreground and `mainActivity` in the background.

**SOLVED**

> For those who wish to know how to open multiple activities parallel from widget
>   OK here is my problem

The string array it should be

```
Intent[] intents={home,intent};
```

instead of

```
Intent[] intents={intent,home};
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivities(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent[],%20int))

Comment: I dont think it's possible.

Comment: Any trick by which i can perform this operation?

Comment: its possible with startActivities(), but its not documented well

Comment: is there any example or proper tutorial available?

Answer (score 2):

Its possible with startActivities(Context, Intent[], bundle). Only Argument here to be explained is  Intent[], which is array of intents of all the activities you need to fire.

Only one Activity (not sure the first or last intent in array, you can experiment on this) , will stay in foreground and remaining will stay in background. When you press back, they will sequentially keep firing until launcher activity.

From docs:

> > public static boolean startActivities (Context context, Intent[] intents, Bundle options)
>
> Start a set of activities as a synthesized task stack, if able.
>
> In API level 11 (Android 3.0/Honeycomb) the recommended conventions
>   for app navigation using the back key changed. The back key's behavior
>   is local to the current task and does not capture navigation across
>   different tasks. Navigating across tasks and easily reaching the
>   previous task is accomplished through the "recents" UI, accessible
>   through the software-provided Recents key on the navigation or system
>   bar. On devices with the older hardware button configuration the
>   recents UI can be accessed with a long press on the Home key.
>
> When crossing from one task stack to another post-Android 3.0, the
>   application should synthesize a back stack/history for the new task so
>   that the user may navigate out of the new task and back to the
>   Launcher by repeated presses of the back key. Back key presses should
>   not navigate across task stacks.
>
> startActivities provides a mechanism for constructing a synthetic task
>   stack of multiple activities. If the underlying API is not available
>   on the system this method will return false.
>
> Parameters context    Start activities using this activity as the
>   starting context intents  Array of intents defining the activities that
>   will be started. The element length-1 will correspond to the top
>   activity on the resulting task stack. options Additional options for
>   how the Activity should be started. See {@link
>   android.content.Context#startActivity(Intent, Bundle) Returns true if
>   the underlying API was available and the call was successful, false
>   otherwise

**UPDATE**

> The element length-1 will correspond to the top activity on the resulting task stack.

so this resolves my confusion too!

**UPDATE**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityTwo.class);
        Intent home= new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        Intent[] intents={home,intent};
        startActivities(context, intents, null);
```

Comment: How can i use the same concept for widget?

Comment: for widget? You mean you want to start multiple activities from widget?

Comment: yeah and i have seen this theres a `getActivities()` method available

Comment: then implement it in your code. whats the confusion?

Comment: cool, please accept the correct one or update it if you have found other source of answer for anyone who is trying to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 10);

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

in this example second activity will opened after first activity closed.

Comment: No i want both to be open at the same time, as i am using widget i need to open two activity at the same time for some reason

Answer (score 0):

1) overwrite onStop() on activity1 and to start activity2.